# stream_copy_to_stream() always returns 0

Tags: php, ajax, fine-uploader

I'm using [Fine-Uploader](http://fineuploader.com) with PHP and something wrong happened. When I use stream_copy_to_stream() in the backend, it always returns 0.

Here's my code in the backend:

```
private function upload_file($file_name, $tmp_name)
{
    $result = array(
            'is_successful' => true,
            'extra_message' => ''
        );

    $target_path = $this->get_target_file_path($file_name, $tmp_name);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path);
    $result['is_successful'] = $this->handle_upload_request($target_path);
    if ( $result['is_successful'] ) {
        $result['extra_message'] = $target_path;
    } else {
        $result['extra_message'] = 'Unknown error occured.<br />';
    }

    return $result;
}

private function handle_upload_request($path)
{
    $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
    $temp = tmpfile();
    $real_size = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
    fclose($input);

    echo $real_size;
    if ($real_size != $this->get_size()){            
        return false;
    }

    $target = fopen($path, "w");        
    fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
    fclose($target);

    return true;
}
```

However, the $real_size always equal to 0. Strangely, the file can be uploaded successfully  sometimes, but sometimes not.

I think maybe it's due to permission in Linux. Because I found that when I uploaded a file, the mod of the file is 644(But I think 644 is enough). And this problem also exists in Windows.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: How/where is `$path` defined?

Comment: Of course. This function will invoked by another function, and the path is the target path to store the file.

Comment: what is the path then?

Comment: It will pass to another function and the function will open the file. However, the function can't open the file properly.

Comment: Then try `$input = fopen("$path", "r");`

Comment: You mean use it in another function to open the file? But it's a third-party library, the code is too long to read.

Comment: From what I saw on their website, this is the upload folder syntax `endpoint: '/uploads'` how is yours setup and where is your `$path` set as? `$input = fopen("$path", "r");` was an example as I don't know what your actual path and/or file field is named.

Comment: So your file's field name is indeed called `fileUploaderfile"` ?

Comment: The solution to your problem is in my answer.  The problem has nothing to do with the `$input` variable.  You should not be using `fopen` or `php://input` to handle a file inside of a multipart encoded POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `php://input`.  `php://input` is used to access the raw request body.   It is empty for multipart encoded requests.  All upload requests sent by Fine Uploader are multipart encoded by default.  Instead, you should grab the file associated with the request using the `$_FILES` superglobal.  There is a [functional PHP example](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php) which will demonstrate this and more for you in the [Fine Uploader server Github repo](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server).

If you insist on writing your own PHP code to handle the requests, you really need to read the [traditional server-side documentation for Fine Uploader](http://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html) first, which tells you that all upload requests are multipart encoded by default.  This is set to the default in order to make it a bit easier to handle upload requests cross-browser, since we need to send the files in a MPE request from IE9 and older always anyway, since IE9 and older do not support uploading files via ajax requests (XHR2).

Comment: When I'm writing this code, I have seen the functional PHP example[https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php] and I have used $_FILES to get file information. Besides, I should make it competiable with IE 8 so I can't use XHR2.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying.  All I am sure of is that the code you have posted in your question is wrong, and the use of `php://input` is the reason for your troubles.  Use `$_FILES` to access the file associated with the request for ALL browsers.

Comment: You mean I should use fopen($_FILES["fileUploaderfile"]['tmp_name'], 'r'); ? But it says: failed to open stream: No such a file or directory. But the file uploaded successfully.

Comment: No, do not use `fopen`.  To move the uploaded file, you should be using `move_uploaded_file`.  Again, look at the server-side example I pointed you at.  The correct way to handle the upload requests is detailed in the server-side example I linked to in my example.

Comment: I have found that if you use move_uploaded_file(), you don't need to use fopen(). Because if you use fopen, PHP will add a file lock to this file.